# python, how to write a desktop application without sharing the secret client credential?

Tags: python, gmail-api

I'm writing a opensource app in python following this example:
 https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python?hl=it

I generated correctly the client_secret.json and ran successfully that example.

Now.. considering I'm starting to write my code and according with google doc:

> **Warning**: Keep your client secret private. If someone obtains your client secret, they could use it to consume your quota, incur charges against your Google APIs Console project, and request access to user data.

so, how can I (in the future) share my app's code and keep at same time the client_secret.json secret?

Comment: I think you need not share client_secret.json. Instead you only share your app and ask next person to keep his/her client_secret.json at particular location.

Comment: I just need a simple way to grant access to GMail account, ask people to create a client_secret.json is out of question

Comment: if i'm not wrong then client_secret.json is credential for app, not for the user. then same file you need to deliver for your app everywhere you are going to install.. Anyways, i was trying to help and i never personally worked on gmail API earlier. :)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I got the answer here:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

> This flow is similar to the one shown in the Using OAuth 2.0 for Web
>   Server Applications, but with three differences:
>
> - When creating a client ID, you specify that your application is an
>     Installed application. This results in a different value for the
>     `redirect_uri` parameter.
> - The client ID and client secret obtained from
>     the Developers Console are embedded in the source code of your
>     application. In this context, the client secret is obviously not
>     treated as a secret.
> - The authorization code can be returned to your
>     application in the title bar of the browser or to an http ://localhost
>     port in the query string.

In other words, if you specify that your project is an "Installed Application" while creating it in the Google APIs Console, you can safely embed secret in your code

Comment: But does doing this somehow mean that the client can't burn your per-project quota? What does it actually mean for it to not be secret?